# Intval возвращает пустую строку

Tags: php

Простой код:

```
 ...
 $id = intval('100');
 echo $id; // пусто!
 exit;
 ...
```

Голову сломал

Comment: предположу, что до этого места код просто не доходит.

Comment: @Etki, нет, именно здесь вывод

Comment: окей, замените на `echo 'here\'s johnny!';`

Comment: код возвращает 100 https://eval.in/490189